# Loading localStorage from different page

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I just made an account so I hope I ask right but anyway. I have two pages. One is a menu and the second one is a HTML game. Now there are two buttons in the menu. One for starting new game and the second for continuing. Now the first button should just put you into the game while the second one load the local storage. Now the problem is the variables don´t come over. I tried making variable that would be saved in menu and then loaded on the second page and if it was 0 it wouldn´t load the variables and if it was 1 it would but that doesen´t work too and I don´t really know what else to do.

THIS IS MY EDITED CODE

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="zacatek()">Play<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="pokracovanifn()">Continue</a>

function load() {
I got rid of the load feature as there was no button for it to use
}

function pokracovani() {
 pokracovani = 1;
 localStorage.setItem("pokracovani", JSON.stringify(pokracovani));
 location.href = "index.html";
}

function zacatek() {
 pokracovani = 0;
 try {
   pokracovani = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pokracovani"));

 } catch (e) {

 }
 location.href = "index.html";
 }
```

And for the game itself

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    pokracovani = 2;
    pokracovani = JSON.parse(localStorage["pokracovani"]);
    if (pokracovani == 0) {

    }
    if (pokracovani == 1) {
            money = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("money"));
            wood = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("wood"));
            stone = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("stone"));
            food = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("food"));
    }
}
}
```

And the saving feature

```
function konec() {
 localStorage["money"] = JSON.stringify(money);
 localStorage["wood"] = JSON.stringify(wood);
 localStorage["stone"] = JSON.stringify(stone);
 localStorage["food"] = JSON.stringify(food);
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the structure of the JSON you are trying to save inside localStorage?

Comment: @tomerpacific you mean like this? localStorage["pokracovani"] = JSON.stringify(pokracovani);

Comment: Please log your `localStorage["pokracovani"]` to console. Copy the JSON and validate it online using JSON formatter. Inside JSON single quoted strings are not allowed. Also check for commas.

Comment: Sorry I am really new to this but I suppose you meant the chrome console right? It just writes me undefined

Comment: It wont work, because a tag is used for navigating. So navigation event is executed before the script runs. Your script is also having errors on JSON parse. So you need to move on with href="javascript:void(0)" approach

Comment: Okay so, that is why it is unable to parse and you are getting that error.

Comment: Here at https://rextester.com/DZQ70235, I have made an example by parsing **undefined**,  I got the same error. Better is to check the parameter before parsing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can u try this code

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="zacatek()">Play</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="pokracovanifn()">Continue</a>

    <script>
        function load() {
            money = 0;
            try{
                JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("money"));
            }catch(e){

            }
        }

        function pokracovanifn() {
            pokracovani = 1;
            localStorage.setItem("pokracovani", JSON.stringify(pokracovani));
             location.href = "/index.html";
        }

        function zacatek() {
            pokracovani = 0;
            try {
                pokracovani = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pokracovani"));

            } catch (e) {

            }
           location.href = "/index.html";
        }


        document.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (document.readyState == "complete") {
                pokracovani = 2;
                try {
                    pokracovani = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pokracovani"));

                } catch (e) {

                }
                if (pokracovani == 0) {

                }
                if (pokracovani == 1) {
                    try {
                        money = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("money"));
                    } catch (e) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, so I put in the code except for the money variable which is stated to be 300. Now, the javascript void 0 says there is nothing I guess? But this was supposed to redict me to the game itself! So should I put in another href? I would also like to know what the catch does if you could but even after all this it still gives me an error : TypeError: pokracovani is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Comment: you can use location.href to redirect to location. I will update that. Forgot to mention it... Coming to TypeError: pokracovani is not a function , you have a variable and function both named pokracovani. Thats why i defined pokracovanifn

Comment: you can use location.reload too if you are not going to use different url

Comment: simply javascript:void(0);  not with index.html. Please refer my code

Comment: Thank you so much! Now just some questions hope you don´t mind. First what does try {} catch (e) {} do? Like try find some variables that are in and load them? Second now I will just put all the variables I want to save into this: function konec() {
  localStorage["money"] = JSON.stringify(money);
  window.close();
} and load them from the document.onreadystatechange right?

Comment: Any program will stop executing if there is an error. So we use try catch block so even if error happens, the code will execute and does not stop. The error can be captured in catch {};

Comment: not sure on your second question. it depends on your logic

Comment: Oh ok. So now I have put in more variables to parse the same way they did but I also have the saving feature but it seems it is fairly broken. Could you maybe take a look at it and tell me what am I doing wrong?